# How can i use jQuery to show/hide some data?

Tags: jquery

i want to have three different 'tabs'. and when a user clicks on the tab, it hides the other two and show the one clicked.

I'm using ASP.NET + jQuery.1.3.2.min

eg.

```
  [ Tab 1]  [ Tab 2 ]  [ Tab 3 ]
---------------------------------
... Table data displayed here ...
```

I was told to use jQuery. I'm not sure about

- The html to write (eg. the tabs and a simple table (i know how to do tables)
- the jquery to wire up to the tabs.

I tried google, but i wasn't getting the correct keywords to find what i was after :(

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) its a JQuery UI plugin.

Answer (score 3):

[Slick implementation of something like that using CSS which will go on top of ASP.NET easily - no jQuery required.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)

Comment: Nice - A List Apart is a great resource.

Comment: Nice link :) but the Tabs thing in jQuery is nice and sweet. cheers anyways :)